# C# constantly streaming serial data to arduino

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I am having trouble streaming comma delimited variables when a certain box is checked. I want the data stream to be constantly flowing to the arduino even if there is no change in the variables. The only time I have been able to get anything close I got stuck in an infinite loop. Here is the current code I have, any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;

namespace feeder3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void streamBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a = 1;
            int b = 2;
            int c = 3;
                bool state = streamBox.Checked;
                while (state == true)
                {
                System.Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", a,b,c);

            }
        }

        private void stopStreamBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            streamBox.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because data transmitted by a serial port takes time to actually send - e.g. At 9600 baud it's about 1 millisecond per byte - but calling the write function returns immediately with the data buffered and transmitted in parallel with your programme continuing to run, if you simple call the write function continuously as you have done then the buffer will fill faster then the data is transmitted. You should delay between calls to write. One way to do that would be use a timer and call the write function in that. Or test for the transmit buffer being empty before calling the write function again,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using the info barny gave me. I can now adjust the delay to match the baudrate.

> ```
>     private async void streamBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         int a = 1;
>         int b = 2;
>         int c = 3;
>             bool state = streamBox.Checked;
>             while (state == true)
>             {
>             System.Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", a,b,c);
>             await Task.Delay(10);
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Is that a 10ms delay? Would be better (more robust) to test for the transmit buffer being empty, for example if the string you are transmitting at 9600 baud is more than 10 or 11 characters with this code you can still keep filling the buffer faster than data actually gets sent.